# In python how we get two numbers after decimal?

Tags: python

```
a=int(input())
b=float(input())
c=a/b
print(format."c{:.2f})
```

I am not getting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick neatly.

```
a=int(input())
b=float(input())
c=a/b
print(round(c,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old issue with floating point numbers, the `round` builtin function doesn't perform as expected, hence you can use these format specifiers corrected from the one in your code.

```
a=int(input())
b=float(input())
c=a/b
print(float(f"{c:.2f}"))
```

Here, you are specifying the float format for the variable `c` and inside the parentheses we use `f` to specify its formatted and inside curly braces we give the variable `c` and restricting it to `.2f` i.e 2 digits after the decimal.